# wedding [of/from] Ann and Bob

Tags: grammar

I am writing a wedding menu. Some guests only speak English, but I'm not a native English speaker.

How would you correctly write this sentence?

> Wedding of Ann and Bob.

or

> Wedding from Ann and Bob.

Comment: *Wedding **of***. (Note, however, that this is not a sentence, merely a phrase: a title or headline, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Wedding of.

This will likely be closed as a 'proofreading' style question, but I think it is useful to point out the power of the [Google NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wedding%20of%2Cwedding%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwedding%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwedding%20from%3B%2Cc0) for answering questions like this. In cases where one answer is extremely rare and the other is many, many times more common, that usually suggests the correct answer.